# Medallion translation

Tags: arabic-translation

I have found this? Any body can give me an idea what's written on it?

Thanks a lot[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOdqD.jpg)

Comment: These kinds of questions are hardly on-topic. As we are not an Arabic language site.

Answer (score 4):

Beginning is the Basmalah:
[image]

> In the name of Allah, the Most Gracious, the Most Merciful

Then what follows are the [verses 255-256](https://quran.com/2/255-256) of Surah Al-Baqarah:
[image]

> Allah - there is no deity except Him, the Ever-Living, the Sustainer
>   of [all] existence. Neither drowsiness overtakes Him nor sleep. To Him
>   belongs whatever is in the heavens and whatever is on the earth. Who
>   is it that can intercede with Him except by His permission? He knows
>   what is [presently] before them and what will be after them, and they
>   encompass not a thing of His knowledge except for what He wills. His
>   Kursi extends over the heavens and the earth, and their preservation
>   tires Him not. And He is the Most High, the Most Great.

[image]

> There shall be no compulsion in [acceptance of] the religion. The right course has become clear from the wrong. So whoever disbelieves in Taghut and believes in Allah has grasped the most trustworthy handhold with no break in it. And Allah is Hearing and Knowing.

Finally, ending with:
[image]

> Almighty Allaah has spoken the truth